# Creating your own distro/backup (or Alternatives to RemasterSys)

Tags: backup, remastersys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)
>   [What are the alternative softwares of remastersys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190133/what-are-the-alternative-softwares-of-remastersys)

I usually use RemasterSys to create a Backup/Distro of my current system with apps intact. But recently, RemasterSys was discontinued. I wonder if there are alternatives to that? If not, I believe I can create a Distro/Backup/Live CD manually? How?

The main objectives is to backup/restore

- apps
- settings
- idealy, user accounts/passwords to be set as new
- live system a plus

Comment: Remastersys is actually resumed, just recently. Check out their [forum](http://www.remastersys.com/forums/index.php?board=38.0). There's a new version there (it's still being tested, but should work fine by now)

Answer (score 1):

Novo builder seems to be the closest software to RemasterSys, however, RemasterSys is still working in 11.04 & 11.10 as the official announcement was made 10/4/11 that the source will still be available in the repositories of Ubuntu for a short period. (http://www.remastersys.com/forums/index.php?topic=1715.0)

Here's a link to Novo Builder: http://www.cyvoc.net/novoweb/screenshots.html