# What are the Alternatives For RemasterSys?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, alternative, remastersys

I need an alternative software of Remastersys since it's not working in my system (Ubuntu 12.04.)

I want software just like remastersys. I don't want to install any new packages, I just want a piece of software that makes an ISO of my current system without any added packages.

Comment: U can try Ubuntu-builder http://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/

Comment: UCK, NOVO builder

Comment: Relinux, reconstructor,ubuntu builder &uck

Comment: Try the new one here: https://github.com/nerun/remastersys

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11857/looking-for-a-free-usable-alternative-for-remastersys/88186#88186

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Relinux**](https://mijyn.github.io/relinux/) is the best software to use instead of Remastersys.

[Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux) is a great tutorial how to use.

Download the latest version from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/relinux/0.3/0.3.0a2/+download/relinux_0.3.0a2.tar.gz)

Comment: `The image created with Relinux can under no circumstances be greater than 4 GB`, this is often the bottleneck to use Relinux.

Comment: http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2014/09/14/im-quitting-relinux/

Answer (score 4):

> Ubuntu Builder is a simple tool to build your own distribution. It allows to download, extract, customize in many ways and rebuild your ubuntu images. You can customize i386 and amd64 images

you can install ubuntu-builder via it [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/) site or via [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~f-muriana/+archive/ubuntu-builder)

Run these commands in gnome-terminal, to install via ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:f-muriana/ubuntu-builder
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-builder
```

---

**Further reading**:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)
- [Is there any guarantee that software from Launchpad PPAs is free from viruses and backdoor threats?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7662/is-there-any-guarantee-that-software-from-launchpad-ppas-is-free-from-viruses-an)

Comment: Ubuntu-builder needs to download packages again and you'll not use the already founded ones in your system so its a bad choice of Remastersys but its great tool (which i tried before) to build from zero

Answer (score 2):

[System Imager](http://system-imaging.blogspot.com.es/) is a fork of Remastersys. The latter is not being developed anymore.

From System Imager's website:

> System Imager is a tool that images your running system and allows you to make a image of your running machine and install it on another. System Imager is based on the work of Remastersys.

It has been released under the GNU GPLv2 and the source code is available from the developers in [Sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/os4online/files/src/System%20Imager/)

Answer (score 1):

Distroshare Ubuntu Imager is a new script that I developed: https://github.com/Distroshare/distroshare-ubuntu-imager .  It is based on this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall, but includes some bug fixes and extras.

System Imager turned into Black Lab Image Creator, which is no longer free.  Re-linux has not been maintained for a while and is no longer under development.

Answer (score 1):

[Pinguy Builder](http://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/) is a tool that works up to Ubuntu 16.04:

> Version 3.* works with *buntu systems 14.04 
>   (May also work with 14.10)
>
> Version 15.10 works with *buntu systems 15.04 & 15.10
>
> Version 4.* works with *buntu systems 16.04

Its description looks quite interesting:

> The Pinguy Builder will create a installable ISO of your current system. You can then burn that ISO to a USB using something like Unetbootin or just burn the ISO directly to a DVD. The DVD/USB can then be booted from a PC.

[image: Imgur]