# Clonning Computer

Tags: installation, apt, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to clone an installation (copying to identical hardware)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2724/best-way-to-clone-an-installation-copying-to-identical-hardware)
>   [Best way to backup all settings, list of installed packages, tweaks, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

I have a computer that installed ubuntu.And i am going to buy another one .

i using my old computer with ubuntu for a year and i installed a lot of program . and i want to install same packages on my new computer . but i dont want install by one by .

**how i can clone programs from old computer to new one ?**

*thanks for helps.*

Comment: Please check this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/190133/what-are-the-alternative-softwares-of-remastersys

Answer (score 3):

You can backup your package list with following command:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > packages
```

This will generate a file called "packages" containing the list of installed packages. Then you must copy that file to the new computer and use the following commands to install packages in the "packages" list:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

Comment: In case of distribution upgrading : some packages have names that include versions and other packages simply disapears. You may have troubles if you change of distribution version. Also be sure to keep your source.list and source.list.d folder copied.