# Full copy of Ubuntu with installed programs and user files

Tags: windows, backup, usb-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the Alternatives For RemasterSys?!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190133/what-are-the-alternatives-for-remastersys)

How to make full copy of Ubuntu (12.04.1), with ability to "unpack" it from Windows, to my another flash card (to have two copy of my Ubuntu OS).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some Ubuntu customization software which allows you to rebuild Ubuntu from the DVD with all needed programs and files. Check [this link from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190133/what-are-the-alternatives-for-remastersys)

Comment: This is really better as a comment,

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what exactly you want to do, but you can create a complete copy of your entire system this way.

First, remove all USB drives and such to make sure we won't include those.

Then, press Ctrl+Alt+T, or use the menu, to open a terminal. Issue this command:

```
sudo tar -cvf system.tar /
```

This will create an archive file in your home directory containing the entire system and all your personal data.

If you're only looking for a backup, it might be sufficient to back up your home directory though, and not the entire system. After all, you can always reinstall the OS and software, but personal data is a lot worse to lose.