# Can I install remastersys on Ubuntu 15.10? What repository should I install?

Tags: backup, remastersys

Every post I see about it seems at least one year old, plus the official website does not provide any link or in-depth description.

Being just a newbie of Ubuntu I'm looking for a software that can make a copy of my whole pc in case I mess things up. If that isn't the right choice please do tell me.

Comment: As of April 28, 2013, the originator's direct development has ceased. try a different backup program: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-outstanding-linux-backup-utilities/ or create a disk image http://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later

Comment: What do you want to do? There is no need for remastersys See http://askubuntu.com/questions/190133/what-are-the-alternatives-for-remastersys

Answer (score 0):

You may add this ppa to your sources, and it also works in Ubuntu ver. 16.04
https://launchpad.net/~kranich/+archive/ubuntu/remastersys